# Java Smack FileTransfer

Tags: java, macos, smack

Okay, I got the following code from the web, and it **does** work:

```
@Override
public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
    // Check to see if the request should be accepted

    final IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
    runnningFileTransfer = transfer;
    try
    {
       final File file = new File("/Users/Akku/Downloads/in2" + request.getFileName());
       transfer.recieveFile(file);
       t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                transfer.recieveFile(file);
                System.out.println("DONE?");
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
       });
       t.run();
```

This code runs, and in the case of my 10MB test file it takes quite a lot of time. Sadly, I need to know if the transfer is finished or what the progress is. Funnily, I also got this part (which just sleeps and checks for progress) from the web, when I append it, the file transfer does not work anymore:

```
       while(!transfer.isDone()) 
       {
            if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error))
            {
                 System.out.println("ERROR"+transfer.getError() + " EX: " + transfer.getException());
            } 
            else 
            {
                 System.out.println("Written: "+transfer.getAmountWritten());
                 System.out.println("STATUS"+transfer.getStatus());
                 System.out.println("PROGRESS"+transfer.getProgress());
            }
        try
        {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("Waiting...");
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
```

Any hint why this might happen? I guess it's something Java, because the above snippet works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The case that works should be throwing an exception.  You call receive twice on the transfer object.  The second call should produce an exception when it tries to create the file again.  The second call, along with the thread creation is not necessary in this case as the transfer() method is asynchronous and has it's own internal threading.

It is hard to say why it doesn't work with your status check, since you don't show where you are doing this check.  My suspicion is that you are calling it on the read thread and thus blocking the reading of new packets.  Your loop checking for the transfer status should be running in its own thread.